# How to decrypt encrypted files by "Cerber Ransomware" in my computer?

Tags: encryption

My computer has injected by the "Cerber Ransomware", and now I couldn't use my important files. How could I decrypt these files without paying the desired money?

Comment: If the ransomware has been made properly then you cannot decrypt the files.  It is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Before giving a sure shot, I would be interested to know which Cerber version you are talking about. If it's Cerber V1, you can easily remove it by using a tool developed by TrendMicro but if it is the latest version which is in between V2 to V6, then you must wait for the tool to be released. There's no solution as of now to remove cerber ransomware from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I went through another Ransomware with "no solution yet" and in order to solve it I used HxD to check the code of the encrypted files, I confronted that with non encrypted files with the same extension (for example, two video files frome the same camera, one encrypted and one not encrypted) and by doing that I have been able to recognize what was wrong in the code, copying and pasting the code from the non encrypted files to the encrypted one. In this way I recovered mainly video and audio files, and it's a good way to recover big files because the ransomware usually encrypts the header of the files and that's it. Anyway remember to always have copies of the crypted files if you try to manipulate it as I did, otherwise you may lose it!